# Error en el archivo R.java "; expected"

Tags: java, android-studio

estoy teniendo un problema en el archivo R.java.
El compilador me dice

> error: ';' expected

en la siguiente línea :

```
public static final int Go!=0x7f080003;
```

Creo que se ha generado mal el archivo R.java
traté quitándole el signo de exclamación a Go pero cuando compilé se volvió a poner.
No entiendo por qué me pide que ponga un ; si al final de la línea está el punto y coma.
Gracias !

Answer (score 0):

En este caso **no vas a solucionar el problema editando el archivo `R.java` ya que este archivo se auto genera en base a los recursos que existen en tu proyecto.**

Lo que debes realizar es renombrar tu recurso y revisar en donde es usado para realizar el cambio de nombre, evita usar caracteres que no sean alfa numéricos o mayúsculas.

> File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or
>   underscore

al renombrar el recurso, como sugerencia a `go` tu archivo cambiara la definición de esta variable en el archivo `R.java`, ejemplo:

```
public static final int go=0x7f080003;
```

Comment: Exacto, el error era porque un Botón tenía como id Go! con signo de exclamación, gracias Jorgesys

Comment: Excelente @MauroStancato , recuerda que cuando alguna respuesta resuelva la problematica planteada en la pregunta puedes marcarla como resuelta con la flecha verde, revisa el [tour], saludos!